# Why are certain log calls not getting displayed in Logcat?

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

I have a certain code snippet like this:

```
Log.i(tmpTag, "B4 URL CHANGE: URL in response = " + responseURL + ".\nLast URL = " + mLastUrl);    //SHOWN IN LOGCAT
if (m_CurrentEventName.contentEquals("forgotpassword")) {
mLastUrl = responseURL.replace("../../../", "");
} else if (m_CurrentEventName.contentEquals("tskstdlogin") &&     responseURL.indexOf("changepassword") != -1) {
mLastUrl = responseURL.replace("../../../", "");
} else {
mLastUrl = responseURL;
}

Log.i(tmpTag, "AFTER URL CHANGE: URL in response = " + responseURL + "\nLast URL = " + mLastUrl);    //NOT SHOWN IN LOGCAT
```

I am expecting both log statements ,but only the first one is getting displayed in LogCat, like this:

```
 08-27 09:39:06.867: I/bindDataTask(1994): B4 URL LOOP: URL in response = "some internal url".
 08-27 09:39:06.867: I/bindDataTask(1994): Last URL = "some internal url".
```

Any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: Is there any exception occured which you handled using try-catch after first log statement prints..

Comment: @CRUSADER Thanks, you were right. Exceptions are logged separately, so missed it at first. Post as an answer, i'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logcat messages contain a number of metadata fields, in addition to the tag and priority. Your first log line got executed so it got printed but other log message didnt get printed because of some exception occured and your program control went to catch section of your try-catch block...

Here...

```
    try{
    Log.i(tmpTag, "B4 URL CHANGE: URL in response = " + responseURL + ".\nLast URL = " + mLastUrl);    //SHOWN IN LOGCAT

    ...
    ...
   // Exception occured..GOTO catch block
    ..
    Log.i(tmpTag, "AFTER URL CHANGE: URL in response = " + responseURL + "\nLast URL = " + mLastUrl);    //NOT SHOWN IN LOGCAT
    .....

    }catch(Exception e){
    Log.e("Exception here...",e.toString());
    }
```